# How to give expression for a textbox when multiple fields are used in the textbox of rdlc?

Tags: rdlc, ssrs-2012

Need to display [Feature] - [FeatureStatus] - [FeaturePerComplete]% if feature field has value or else need to display N/A, what expreession do I need to give for this
[image]

Comment: Gave the expression this expression =IIf(Fields!Feature.Value Is Nothing, "N/A",Fields!Feature.Value & " - " & Fields!FeatureStatus.Value & " - " & Fields!FeaturePerComplete.Value & "%")

Comment: the above expression is working

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
=IIf(Fields!Feature.Value Is Nothing, "N/A",Fields!Feature.Value & " - " & Fields!FeatureStatus.Value & " - " & Fields!FeaturePerComplete.Value & "%")
```

to..

```
=IIf(Isnothing(Fields!Feature.Value), "N/A",Fields!Feature.Value & " - " & Fields!FeatureStatus.Value & " - " & Fields!FeaturePerComplete.Value & "%")
```

This relies on the Feature column being null in those circumstances - will it definitely be null, or will it be blank?